Writing a png image from scratch in C++ after compression via zlib
My goal is to write a png image from a starting bitmap image. I know the existence of many libraries, but I need to write it from scratch.
The first function I have implemented is "applyNoneFilter"
uchar* applyNoneFilter(const uchar* input, int width, int height)
{
    uint8_t* output = new uchar[width * (height + 1)];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        output[y * (width + 1)] = 0;
        memcpy(output + y * (width + 1), input + y * width, width);
    }

    return output;
}

I pass the image data via img.ptr(), the raw data from an image loaded via OpenCV. The function just add a 0 before each scanlines, implementing the first step in png creation: filtering.
I pass the filtered output to the writeCompressedDataToPNG function I wrote:
void writeCompressedDataToPNG(const uint8_t* input, const std::string& filename, uint32_t width, uint32_t height) {
    std::ofstream outFile(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if (!outFile) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open file for writing");
    }

    // PNG Header
    const unsigned char pngHeader[8] = { '\211', 'P', 'N', 'G', '\r', '\n', '\032', '\n' };
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pngHeader), 8);

    // IHDR Chunk
    unsigned char ihdrChunk[25] = {
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0D, // Length of IHDR data
      'I', 'H', 'D', 'R',
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Width placeholder
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Height placeholder
      0x08,                   // Bit depth: 8
      0x00,                   // Color type: 0 (grayscale)
      0x00,                   // Compression method: Deflate
      0x00,                   // Filter method: No filtering
      0x00,                   // Interlace method: 0
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00  // CRC placeholder
    };

    intToBigEndian(width, &ihdrChunk[8]);
    intToBigEndian(height, &ihdrChunk[12]);

    uint32_t crc = crc32(0, ihdrChunk + 4, 17);
    intToBigEndian(crc, &ihdrChunk[21]);

    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ihdrChunk), 25);


    // IDAT chunk
    uLongf compression_size = compressBound(width * (height + 1));
    std::vector<uchar> compressed(compression_size);
    int result = compress(compressed.data(), &compression_size, input, width * (height + 1));
    if (result != Z_OK)
    {
        std::cerr << "Compression failed" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    compressed.resize(compression_size);
    uint32_t chunkLength = compressed.size();
    unsigned char chunkLengthBytes[4];
    intToBigEndian(chunkLength, chunkLengthBytes);

    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(chunkLengthBytes), 4);

    unsigned char chunkType[4] = { 'I', 'D', 'A', 'T' };
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(chunkType), 4);

    uint32_t crc_idat = crc32(0, chunkType, 4); // Include "IDAT" chunk type

    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(compressed.data()), compressed.size());
    crc_idat = crc32(crc_idat, compressed.data(), compressed.size());

    unsigned char crcBytes[4];
    intToBigEndian(crc_idat, crcBytes);
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(crcBytes), 4);

    // IEND Chunk
    const unsigned char iendChunk[12] = {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        'I', 'E', 'N', 'D',
        0xAE, 0x42, 0x60, 0x82
    };
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(iendChunk), 12);

    outFile.close();
}

The function intToBigEndian is this one, it convert an integer to a bigendian representation according to the png specifications.
void intToBigEndian(uint32_t value, unsigned char* buffer) {
    buffer[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
    buffer[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    buffer[2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    buffer[3] = value & 0xFF;
}

It creates an image that I can correctly visualize in the Windows image visualizer, when I try to load it via code with OpenCV imread I got the error libpng error: bad adaptive filter value.
I understand that I messed up the IDAT chunk writing, in particular the filter. But I cannot see the problem. I have also checked the crc with png-file-chunk-inspector and everything appears to be fine. So, where is my error?

Instead of trying to eyeball the result, why not use a debugger? Write a small program using the stb_image loader and step through it. The code is simple and any errors will stand out immediately.

here's where libpng is failing https://github.com/pnggroup/libpng/blob/c1cc0f3f4c3d4abd11ca68c59446a29ff6f95003/pngread.c#L544 a debugger should show you what is happening

@AlanBirtles yes, but I do not understand why. I put 0 both in the filter method field inside the idhr chunk, both at the starting of each scanline during the filtering

See http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.IDAT, Note that with filter method 0, the only one currently defined, this implies prepending a filter-type byte to each scanline., have you done that?

@AlanBirtles this is what I do in applyNoneFilter function. I prepend a 0 for each scanline

You're overwriting the "filter type" byte on the immediately following line. You also want the size (width + 1) * height rather than width * (height + 1).

Valgrind is already complaining about "Invalid write of size 2" in your applyNoneFilter, so I wouldn't even try to implement anything after that. Don't write 1k lines of code and then debug, implement your project in small steps, and test each step before moving forward,

The problem stems from this line:
memcpy(output + y * (width + 1), input + y * width, width);

the corrected implementation of applyNoneFilter:
uchar* applyNoneFilter(const uchar* input, int width, int height)
{
    uint8_t* output = new uchar[height * (width + 1)];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        output[y * (width + 1)] = 0; // Set filter type to 0 for "None"
        memcpy(output + y * (width + 1) + 1, input + y * width, width);
        // Copy the scanline starting from the second byte of the output buffer
    }
    return output;
}

The first byte of each scanline in the filtered output must be the filter type (in this case, 0 for the None filter).
In your original code, memcpy overwrites the 0 that was set for the filter type because you started copying at output + y * (width + 1), instead of output + y * (width + 1) + 1.
